# Texture Brush in SVG with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, css, svg, graphics

Is there something in SVG that works like TextureBrush in C#? I need something in JavaScript that looks like this

```
var brush = TextureBrush(image);
```

Comment: There is `<pattern>`. Maybe you should start by looking at [these](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-pattern-element/) [two](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-pattern-attributes/) tutorials to find out how to use images as patterns.